# Writing Grover's Iterator in different computational phase

Tags: grovers-algorithm

This question is from Nielson and Chuang's *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information*:

[image: question_image]

Here $|\alpha\rangle$ is given by:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N-M}}\sum_{x} "|x\rangle $$
where $\sum_{x}" |x\rangle$ is the sum of states which are not the solution.

and $|\beta\rangle $ is given by:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}\sum_{x} ' |x\rangle $$
where it represents all $M$ solutions.

$\theta$ is defined by:
$$\cos\Big(\frac{\theta}{2}\Big) = \sqrt{\frac {N-M}{N}}$$

I understand everything mentioned above as well as the further geometric visualization. However, I am having trouble trying to come up with a justified way to solve this exercise. The only thing that I understand is that $G$ must be a unitary Matrix made up of trigonometric functions. How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite $|\psi\rangle$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ i.e.
$$
|\psi\rangle = \cos(\theta/2)|\alpha\rangle + \sin(\theta/2)|\beta\rangle
$$ 
Also, G rotates the state vector by $\theta$ towards $\beta$.
$$
G|\psi\rangle = \cos(3\theta/2)|\alpha\rangle + \sin(3\theta/2)|\beta\rangle
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12}\\
    x_{21}       & x_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta/2)\\
    \sin(\theta/2)\\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(3\theta/2)\\
    \sin(3\theta/2)\\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta)\cos(\theta/2)-\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta/2)\\
    \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta/2)+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta/2)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
By comparison, you can find the value of $x_{11},x_{12},x_{21}$ and $x_{22}$, and hence, G which comes out to be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta) && -\sin(\theta)\\
    \sin(\theta) && \cos(\theta)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$